# Symfony2 on Ubuntu 14.4.01 Subdomain - Missing assets

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, ubuntu, plesk

Somehow the routing isn't understanding where to get my assets, its missing 3 css files for the basic demo:

```
http://sub. domain.ext/bundles/framework/css/structure.css
http://sub.domain.ext/bundles/framework/css/body.css
http://sub.domain.ext/bundles/framework/css/exception.css
```

The server runs Ubuntu and has Plesk installed.

So on /var/www/vhosts/system/sub.domain.ext/conf/vhost.conf

I've told the server to look for my project:

```
ServerName sub.domain.ext
ServerAlias www.sub.domain.ext

DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/sub.domain.ext/projectmanagement/web
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/sub.domain.ext/projectmanagement/web>
    # enable the .htaccess rewrite
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_acces.log combined
```

Ive also tried adding the templating -> assets_base_url to the config.yml but nothing matters, I keep on getting the missing assets.

If someone has had experience with subdomains and symfony2 before, please let me in on the secret to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

Check list that you might want to go through

1. Did you run the command `php app/console assets:install` to make sure assets are installed and available
2. I am not sure how you are calling assets in your view/twig but if you are using {{ assets_url }} then you will also need to run the command `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` this will physically place the assets in web folder to be used in production environment.
3. if you are including the stylesheet in this way `{% stylesheets 'bundles/bundlename/css/*'%}` then remember to add `cssrewrite` like `{% stylesheets 'bundles/bundlename/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}`

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the checklist, it didn't work sadly enough.
I should have mentioned more clearly that Im only trying to see either the acmedemo or an empty project and that the Symfony error/notice css (the framework css) is not being loaded. I think it has to do with the fact thats it's a subdomain and the .htaccess doesn't know what to do, but I'm not that server savvy. Take a look here: [link](http://marius.kladblok.net/app_dev.php)

Comment: The link gives me 404 error. In your case I think you should first setup symfony without making any Apache configuration changes and once it is working only then change Apache configuration. Symfony should work fine in sub domain or a directory

Comment: Its a 404 because its an empty app, so theres no indexAction, but ill try again and get back to you

Comment: [link](http://85.214.38.12:8000/) I have no problems running it like this (when using php app/console server:start ip.ip.ip.ip:port
So why is setting it up for Apache not working :(

Comment: it is really hard to say, i am getting 403 forbidden error, check your logs for error

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I think that has to do with the fact I am working in dev, not sure though. Can't reproduce the 403. But still, I know how to develop with Symfony, I just can't seem to set up the apache correctly. Thanks for taking your time to help me out

Comment: sorry to hear that you are stuck. Maybe you should get hold of someone in your circle who knows more about server configuration.

Comment: Well, I wanted to show to a friend how it's supposed to work and what I had tried etc. Aaaand it works.. No clue what I did differently this time. Thx for your time!

Comment: I glad its finally sorted :) must be feeling relaxed